# SVG font differs between browsers

Tags: internet-explorer, google-chrome, fonts, svg, adobe-illustrator

Hopefully just a quick problem - My friend's logo is an SVG image and it looks perfect in Chrome - (Futura/Helvetica fonts used), yet in IE, (And possibly other browsers?) the font (and the kerning) is completely different. I can provide images if needed.

Is there a way I can save that stops the browser tampering with the font? Keeping how it looks exactly in Illustrator/Chrome? I'd much rather leave it as SVG than convert it to PNG or anything else.

I have a feeling this is a repost (Although I couldn't find an answer) - Sorry!

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Some pictures would indeed be helpful, as well as the SVG code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Converting the text to a path will store the exact geometry of each letter in the file, at the cost of making the file a little bigger. Here is an article on how to do it: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/illustrator/cs/using/WS714a382cdf7d304e7e07d0100196cbc5f-63d0a.html#WS18156339-458C-45e1-8CD0-DD7931678BBE

Comment: Thank you! I think that's exactly what I'm after, such a simple fix, for something that was giving me quite the headache :)